# Фамилия Базовод

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Нам выдали аттестат на имя Базоводу Александру Сергеевичу,( Базовод) подскажите правильно ли нам написали ?

Answer (score 2):

Мужская фамилия Базовод склоняется, так как оканчивается на согласный и соответствует 2-му склонению существительных. Несклонение таких фамилий считается ошибкой, отступлением от нормы.

Склоняемость  мужских фамилий на согласный обсуждается  только в особых случаях, например  при различных совпадениях (профессор Маршал А.В. - наградить профессора Маршал А.В.).